# Javascript form validation submit function is being called only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shopify

So I have the JQuery code here:

```
$(function() {

  const $facesSelectorContainer = $('.faces-select');
  if ($facesSelectorContainer) {

    // store some variables
    const $hiddenFacesSelector = $('.selection-wrapper-faces'),
      $facesButtons = $facesSelectorContainer.find('.faces-container'),
      $facesSelector = $hiddenFacesSelector.find('select'),
      $facesUpload = $('.faces-upload'),
      $facesUploadFields = $facesUpload.find('.face-upload-container');

    // upload the number of faces upload inputs visible
    function updateFacesNumber(e) {
      const number = parseInt($facesSelector.val());

      for(let i = 0, max = $facesUploadFields.length; i < max; i++) {
        const $field = $facesUploadFields.eq(i), $input = $field.find('input[type="file"]');
        $field.toggle(i < number).removeClass('required');
        if (i >= number) {
          $input.prop('required', false);
        } else {
          $input.prop('required', true);
        }
        $input.trigger('change');
      }
      $facesButtons.removeClass('selected');
      $facesButtons.filter(`[data-faces-number="${number}"]`).addClass('selected');
    }

    $('.faces-container').on('click', (e) => {
        const j = $(e.target).closest('.faces-container').index()-1;
        console.log(j);
        $('.faces-container').removeClass('selected');
        $(e.target).closest('.faces-container').addClass('selected');

        $facesUploadFields.removeClass('show');
        for ( let g=1;g<=j;g++)
            $facesUploadFields.eq(g).addClass('show');

    });
    updateFacesNumber();
    setTimeout(updateFacesNumber, 10); // re-update after 10ms, so that images in cache will be loaded
    $facesSelector.on('change', updateFacesNumber);

    // update the faces number on click
    $facesSelectorContainer.on('click', '.faces-container', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
      const value = $(this).data('faces-number');
      $facesSelector.val( value ).trigger('change');
    });


    // handle uploads
    $facesUploadFields.on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function() {
      const file = this.files, $this = $(this), $field = $this.closest('.face-upload-container'), $image = $field.find('.preview-image'), $remove = $field.find('.remove'), $required = $field.find('.required');
      if (file.length) {
        $field.removeClass('empty required');
        const blob = window.URL.createObjectURL(file[0]);
        $image.css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + blob + ')' }).addClass('visible');
        $image.addClass('show');
        $remove.addClass('show');
        $required.addClass('hide');
      } else {
       // $('#AddToCart').attr('disabled','disabled');
        //$('#AddToCart').css({ opacity: 0.5 });
        $field.addClass('empty');
        $image.css({ 'background-image': '' }).removeClass('visible');
        $image.removeClass('show');
        $remove.removeClass('show');
        $required.removeClass('hide');
      }
      /*if($('.empty.show').length===0 && $('#type-dogs-name').val().length ){
        console.log('radi');
        $('#AddToCart').removeAttr('disabled'); 
        $('#AddToCart').css({ opacity: 1 });
      }*/


    }).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
      const $this = $(this), $field = $this.closest('.face-upload-container'), $input = $field.find('input[type="file"]');
      $input.val(null).trigger('change');
    });
/*
    // display "required" message on form submit
    $('#AddToCart').unbind();
    $('#AddToCart').off();
    $('#AddToCart').prop("onclick", null).off();

    $form = $('form[action="/cart/add"]');
    $form.off();
    $form.find(":submit").prop("onclick", null).off();
*/


    $('#AddToCart').on('click submit', function(e) {
     const number = parseInt($facesSelector.val());
      const button = $(this);
      let can_submit = true;
      for(let i = 0, max = $facesUploadFields.length; i < max; i++) {        
        const $field = $facesUploadFields.eq(i), $input = $field.find('input[type="file"]');
        if (i < number && !$input[0].files.length) {
          $field.addClass('required');
          can_submit = false;
        }
        if($facesUploadFields.eq(i).hasClass("empty") && $facesUploadFields.eq(i).css('display') != 'none') 
          can_submit=false;

        if (i >= number) {
          $input.val(null);
        }
      }

      if(!$('#type-dogs-name').val()){
        $('#type-dogs-name').before('<span class="error">This field is required</span>');
        $('.error').removeClass('hide');
        $('#type-dogs-name').addClass('required');
        can_submit=false;
      }

      if(can_submit===false) {
        button.off();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();        
        button.addClass('disabled');
        //button.css({ opacity: 0.5 });
        //button.attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#AddToCartForm').off(); 
      }
      else {
        button.on();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        button.removeClass('disabled');
        button.css({ opacity: 0.5 });
        button.removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#AddToCartForm').on();
        $('#AddToCartForm').submit(); 
      }

    });
    $("#type-dogs-name").click(function(){
      if($('.empty.show').length===0 && $('#type-dogs-name').val().length){
        console.log('radi');
        $('#AddToCart').removeAttr('disabled'); 
        $('#AddToCart').css({ opacity: 1 });
      }
      $('.error').addClass('hide');
      $("#type-dogs-name").removeClass('required');
    });
    /*$("#type-dogs-name").change(function(){
      if($('.empty.show').length===0 && $('#type-dogs-name').val().length){
        console.log('radi');
        $('#AddToCart').removeAttr('disabled'); 
        $('#AddToCart').css({ opacity: 1 });
      }
    });*/
  }
});
```

I've been working on it a bit long so you'll see some things commented which I was trying to implement the best solution.

The website is here: https://pawdie.com/products/custom-dog-doormat
It is run on Shopify. So I'm trying to make some validations to the form. If you try submitting the form (Add To Cart button) and you haven't inserted all the pictures and the name in the text field you will not be able to submit but instead it will show you an error. Which is how it was supposed to work. But when I try and submit the form again without still adding all the needed things(pictures and text in the input field) it will submit and not show the error.

So my guess is: It's somehow passing the validation function which I'm not sure why is happening. If someone could help I would be really grateful. Thanks!

Comment: There may be another part of code that removes the events from the submit, thus disabling your validation. This is especially true on shopify where are multiple apps from multiple vendors installed on the same theme and displayed on same page. You should test your code outside shopify (from the really quick look I took it looks ok regarding the problem you mentioned, although there are tons of things to be improved - but you say is work in progress so won't mention them). Another quick note... those stopPropagations will DESTROY any other apps that use that button. You should rethink it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think the add to cart may be used by another application. Will try disable it and see what happens. But if that’s true then why it works the first time and the second time it’s being skipped?

Comment: That is just a feeling, not 100% sure. But... it may work in 2 ways. If some other app event is processed after yours (this may happen even with your stopPropagation, in 2 ways, later trigger and delayed execution) and it unbinds all events for some reason second execution will not be triggered. If is called before without stop propagation it may unbind and your validation still work first time (this is a resource race so not sure on this case). Anyway best way to investigate would be to add a console log in the function and see if it appears. If it doesn't then the event is the issue.